# How can I troubleshoot bluetooth occasionally restarting on MacBooks?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth

During the last 4 years I've had 3 different MacBooks (one personal, two from different jobs) that had the same issue: bluetooth randomly dropped all connections. I typically have a bluetooth keyboard, mouse and headphones connected but headphones are typically optional.

If it happened with one machine, I would blame myself for messing something up or maybe faulty hardware in that particular unit. However, this is my third macbook that's suffering from the exact same issue. Bluetooth either comes back after a few minutes or I restart the thing manually. It's a bit annoying during conference calls.

Is this by any means a known issue and something I could do anything about?

Answer (score 0):

I have never experienced such an issue on any of my Macs. I haven't heard others complain about it either.

As far as I understand, you're saying that Bluetooth stops working for a few minutes every once in a while - even with only a keyboard and a mouse connected - and it happens often enough that you're impacted even within a single conference calls.

I would try using wired devices and only having a single Bluetooth connected device. Try different combinations to see if you can single out a faulty device.

If that doesn't help, try going to other locations and see if the problems goes away. You might be dealing with interference from a noise source, which have affected all 3 Macs in the same way.